# How to compute equation 1.68 of Bishop's book

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, pattern-recognition

I am trying to obtain the right hand side of equation 1.68 in *[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387310732)* by Bishop.
I was treating the problem as having four random variables $x,t,D,w$ where $D=(X,T)$ then I only obtain this:

$$P(t,x,D)=\int P(t,x,D,w)dw$$
$$P(t|x,D)P(x,D)=\int P(t|x,D,w)P(x,D,w)dw$$
$$P(t|x,D)=\int P(t|x,D,w)P(w|x,D)dw$$

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: Please use math typesetting. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: We're not copyright police, but a pdf of a whole textbook seems a bit much to swallow. I've changed the link. If that makes your question harder to follow for someone without the text in front of them, note that questions are supposed to be self-contained anyway - to at least make sense without reference to external sources. Quote relevant parts if you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book sneakily invoked the concept of "conditional independence".

Suppose we have variables $A,$ $B,$ and $C,$ and that $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent *given* $C.$ This means that $P(A \mid B, C) = P(A \mid C).$ That is, if $C$ is observed, then $A$ is independent of $B.$ However, that independence is *conditional*, so it's still true that $P(A \mid B) \ne P(A)$ in general.

In this case, $t$ is conditionally independent of $D$ *given* $w.$ The reason for this is that $t$ solely depends on $w$ and $x,$ but if you don't know $w$ then $D$ gives you a *hint* to the value of $w.$ However, if you *do* know $w$ then $D$ is no longer useful for determining the value of $t.$ This explains why $D$ was omitted from $P(t \mid x, w, D)$ but not from $P(t \mid x, D).$

Similarly, $w$ is entirely independent of $x$ so $P(w \mid x, D) = P(w \mid D).$

Comment: Now it makes sense, thanks! so just to confirm, is my derivation correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I thought I'd post this for anyone else googling this equation. The derivation, as Bishop says, proceeds by using the sum and product rules, and it's pretty straightforward that way. The following proof makes it clear just where the sum and product rules are being used.

\begin{align}
 p(t|x, \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{t}) &= \int p(t, \mathbf{w} | x, \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{t}) \rm{d}\mathbf{w}\tag{sum rule}\\
 &= \int p(t|x, \mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{t}) p(\mathbf{w}|x, \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{t}) \rm{d}\mathbf{w} \tag{product rule}\\
 &= \int p(t|x, \mathbf{w}) p(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{t}) \rm{d}\mathbf{w} \tag{drop variables}
\end{align}

We drop variables at the final step because, for example, the new prediction depends only on the new test point and the weights, not on the full training data.